# init parameter using servletconfig not working

Tags: servlets, web.xml

in `web.xml` file

```
<init-param>
    <param-name> n1 </param-name>
    <param-value> 100 </param-value>
 </init-param>

 <init-param>
    <param-name> n2 </param-name>
    <param-value> 200 </param-value>
 </init-param>
```

servlet file is:

```
ServletConfig conf=getServletConfig();
String s1=conf.getInitParameter("n1");
String s2=conf.getInitParameter("n2");
out.println("n1 value is " +s1+ " and n2 is " +s2);
```

it returns null value of n1 and n2

Comment: Put all web.xml please

Comment: thaks guys i got the answer.actually there is a problem in a web.xml i used the wrong servlet name.